# Screen reader not reading model window automatically

Tags: html, jsp, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am trying on a JSP model window is not read automatically by a screen reader. This modal window is a second modal window first modal window is read automatically. But not the second model window.

Here is the code:

```
<div id=second-popup style="display:none" aria-live="polite" role="dialog"> 

<input type="hidden" id="none-label" value="nonetext"/>
<jsp:include page="somepagelinkhere.jsp" flush="true"/>
<html:hidden property="intialized"/>
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2">
<div class="div3">
<div class="div4">
<html:select styleId="" property="">
<html:options collection="" property="">
</html:select>
<html:select styleId="" property="">
<html:options collection="" property="">
</html:select>
</div>
<c:set var="var1"><bean:message  /></c:set>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="removelabel">


<div class="div5">
<form:label property="" >
<select name="country" id="countrylabel" class="country" >
<option value="">${countrieslist}</option>
<c:forEach var="" items="">
<option value=""> ${countrieslists}</option>
</forEach> 
</div>

<div id="city" class="citylist">
<form:label property="">
<select name="" id="" class="">
<option value=""></options>
</select>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>

,showhide: function(){ 
$("button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault;
$("button").attr("aria-hidden","true");
$("second-popup").attr("style","display:block");
$("second-popup").attr("aria-hidden","false");
});
}


$(document).ready(function(){
$("first-popup").attr("tabindex",0);
$("first-popup").attr("tabindex",0);
$("Second-popup").focus();
});
```

In the above code first `div` contains second modal window content code blue print. I need this to be read automatically read by NVDA screen reader 
and I tried by putting `role="dialog" aria=labelledby="id" aria-describedby=""` on the parent `div`, but still screen reader is not reading automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the screen reader automatically read the content of a modal overlay with a combination of the following on my overlay section:

```
aria-labelledby="title_id" aria-describedby="body_id" aria-live="assertive"
```

plus setting the focus to the autofocus element in the overlay content:

```
overlay.querySelector('*[autofocus]').focus();
```

It only worked with all these things together.